# So many names in this place

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

The spelled name of this **one word** place is kind of interesting

It has within its name:

> 1. Three first names
> 2. One last name
> 3. One name of a country
> 4. One name of a Province/State/Territory
> 5. One name of a city
> 6. Name of a college/university -- kind of.

All the names above, as they are spelled, appear uninterrupted or unbroken in the original word. (so if the first name is John it appears as john not j__ohn). Just an example. John is not in the word.

No rearranged letters of course. Names do not necessarily appear in the order I have given above

I think this is simple enough so no computers are needed.

Hint

> The place is a city

Comment: No computers? Fair enough...but I still can't think of a way to do it with a computer :))

Comment: Just as a question, how common do the first/last names have to be?

Comment: Names are quite common

Comment: Are those first names and the last name popular *Western* names (e.g. Max, Sam)? Or more generically, are they something used globally (e.g. John), or are they very region specific (e.g. Ram, which is Indian)?

Comment: Popular Western Names

Comment: I bet the answer is one of the [long place names list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_place_names), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Indianapolis

Three first names

> Ana, Diana, Oli

One last name

> Dia (e.g, footballer Ali Dia)

One name of a country

> India

One name of a Province/State/Territory

> Indiana

One name of a city

> Napoli

Name of a college/university -- kind of.

> OLI - [Oxford Learning Institute](https://www.learning.ox.ac.uk/)

Comment: hexomino, great. Surprised that you missed Ian as a name. There is another University (kind of ) here too